# Postgresql database with PHP server error on MacOS Bash

Tags: php, bash, macos, postgresql, homebrew

I ran a PHP server with postgresql on my college computers which works fine, however on my local machine (which runs MacOS), I get the following error message:

```
Call to undefined function pg_Connect() in /Users/mac/Documents/<... the remaining path to php file>.php on line 2
```

Now, I thought it's an issue of missing the postgresql packages for php, so I used brew to install the php postgresql packages. I ran the following commands:

```
brew install postgresql
brew install php55 --with-postgresql
brew install php55-pdo-pgsql
```

However, even after running these commands I get the same error when running the php server, i.e.

```
Call to undefined function pg_Connect() in /Users/mac/Documents/<... the remaining path to php file>.php on line 2
```

The php version I have is 5.5.30:

```
mac$ php -v
PHP 5.5.30 (cli) (built: Oct 23 2015 17:21:45) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

Please could you suggest what I am doing wrong to install the packages. I read on stack overflow that the packages can be installed with an apt-get command on linux, however I'm not sure as to what the solution is with the Mac operating system.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please run `postgres -V` command and check your posgress version. If postgress installed correctly then it will show you the version number and details.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I think postgres is installed correctly but I can't access it via php, e.g. I can't use functions such as pg_connect() from php.

Comment: I get the following output from postgres -V: postgres (PostgreSQL) 10.3

Answer (score 1):

The solution was edit the php.ini on your server then find this below line and uncomment that line.

```
extension="pgsql.so"
```

then restart the server apache and test it out again.

Also, check [this link](https://www.codementor.io/engineerapart/getting-started-with-postgresql-on-mac-osx-are8jcopb) for the steps regarding installation of the postgress to mac OS.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. I checked the php.ini file (under /etc directory) and could not find the line: extension="pgsql.so". However the following lines were present: extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll and extension=php_pgsql.dll. I uncommented both of these and restarted the server (I'm running local server) and tried again but it did not work. Any possible reasons for this?

Comment: i get the following output: postgres (PostgreSQL) 10.3

Comment: I just checked the link you gave (thanks for that), I am able to view the postgres tables from the command line as mentioned in the link, however I think the problem is with accessing postgres via PHP. I'm not completely sure though.

Comment: Ok then might be that will be the problem because postgress is fine in your case. Please upvote/accept my answer if that helpful to you. Thanks. @AmishBedi

Comment: Ok, thanks I'll try to figure out what's wrong. Thanks for helping out anyway!